# Correcting for multiple comparisons using simulated distribution

Tags: multiple-comparisons, resampling, permutation-test

To check if unilateral pairs (defined below*) are coordinated (i.e. move together) in a flock of N coordinated individuals, we generate hypothetical (null) distribution of a certain focal parameter of our system (the frequency that 2 individuals are nearest neighbors along a track). The null model is simulated by shuffling the empirical data in a way that should break down coordination among pairs (changing the initial conditions and the fluctuations from the mean path along the track), repeated 5000 times. We then calculate the very same parameter for all N(N-1) unilateral pairs in the empirical data. For each unilateral pair, the null distribution should indicate the probability of getting the empirical value (or higher) of the focal parameter if the flock moves without coordination among pairs. But since we check all possible N(N-1) unilateral pairs, we engage multiple comparisons. We would greatly appreciate suggestions how to correct for multiple comparisons in this case.

- unilateral pairs - (A->B) or (B->A) but not necessarily A<->B (this is a bilateral pair)

Best wishes,

Ran

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only generate the null-distribution of *one* focal parameter and subsequently calculate *one* p-value based on the permutation. This is still one one-sided statistical test, no matter how larger the dataset or how many permutations. Multiple testing corrections do not apply here as a result.